# Microsoft Edge shows a white space while chrome/Internet explorer do not

Tags: html, css, asp.net, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

for a school project we've been working on a website which uses a schedule and, even though its not necessary, I wanted to make it work on all browsers. When I opened the page on Microsoft Edge, my 'Thead' (table head) element (shown below) showed up with a giant whitespace at the bottom of it. Picture for reference;

Left: **Chrome** Right: **Microsoft Edge**

[image]
This is the CSS used for this part.

```
.fixed_header thead tr {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.fixed_header thead {
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
}
```

and this is the CShtml part where things go wrong.

```
   <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><a>Week: @(ViewData["weeks"])</a></th>
            @{string[] days = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" };}

            @for (int i = 0; i < days.Length; i++)
            {
        <th>
            @(days[i]) <a >@Html.Action("ReturnDateOfWeek", "Application", new { year = DateTime.Now.Year, weekOfYear = ViewData["weeks"], DayOfWeek = i }) </a>
        </th>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

I've searched the entire document but noone added anything extra. Those are the only 2 definitions for Thead. I tried to change all the values and nothing changed. I also use 'Tbody' tags which work fine aswell. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I have little to no experience in web development in particular.

I don't think it has anything to do with it but Im using razor pages with asp.net MVC.

** Updates with new f12 results. 
All styles active on the Thead element(which includes the white space);

[image]

Computed styles for the thead element;

[image]

Comment: Could you post the code for the entire table? And the output code you see in DevTools too.

Comment: Use Inspect Element in the Developer Tools, and see what is taking up all of the space, maybe it's carrying forward a different property such as margin or something.

Comment: I have created a sample using your code, the result [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XH9sn.png), it seems that everything works well. Please try to use F12 developer tools to check the HTML elements and CSS style, whether the table element contains the right format? whether there have any other CSS style which might cause this issue? And, which version of Microsoft Edge browser are you using? Try to clear the cache and recheck the web page. If still not working, can you post enough code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I added some more screeshots of the computed css results and am looking through them now. Thanks for the suggestions, I did have an update waiting which I am going to download later today. Clearing cache did not work.

Comment: @coder, Can't reproduce the problem using the screenshot, can you post the Enough code (instead of the screenshot) to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you could also using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tpus18v4/) or [codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/), also  you could create a similar application about this part and share the related code.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop looks like it's making messed up HTML..  seems to be closing th twice, for example and not closing the row on each row.

should be:

```
<thead>
 <tr>
   <th>
    Stuff here
   </th>
 </tr>

 <tr>
   <th>
     Another Row
   </th>
 </tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: I can't seem to find what you're refering too. I create the Thead, which is styling, then I create a <tr>, which is the upper-most row. Which has 8  <td's> in it. The first one is <th><a>Week: @(ViewData["weeks"])</a></th> which is opened and closed, THEN I start the loop which opens and closes a <th>. I don''t think thats the problem if im not missing anything.